# How to update multiple data with implode in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, implode

I have a script for inserting multiple data in PHP with `implode` method but I don't know how to use it in UPDATE syntax.

```
<input type="text" name="field_name" value="unyil"/>
```

With PHP like this:

```
foreach($_POST['id_table'] as $row=>$id_table)
{
    $id_table=$id_table;
    $full_name=$_POST['full_name'][$row];

    $query_row[] = "('$id_table','$full_name')";
}

$sql="INSERT INTO tb_client_table_rows (id_table, full_name) VALUES " . implode(',',$query_row); 

if (!mysql_query($sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

But how can I use that for UPDATING row values?

Comment: Why would you want to use implode?

Comment: Ripe for SQL injection; use PDO and parametrized queries.

Comment: What are typical and max number of rows you expect to be updated in such a manner? How do the number of rows which you expect to update compare to the total number of rows in the table? This may have significant impact on what approach may be most efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mohamed Hossam has posted the following in a comment to the [MySQL reference manual (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150924140206/https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html#c6075):

> A very server resources friendly method to update multiple rows in the same table is by using `WHEN THEN` (with a very important note).
>
> ```
> UPDATE tbl_name SET fld2 = CASE fld1
> WHEN val1 THEN data1
> WHEN val2 THEN data2
> ELSE fld2 END
> ```
>
> The note is: **do not forget `ELSE`**. If you do not use it, all rows that are outside the range of your updated values will be set to blank!

(Emphasis and formatting added.)

---

Based on this, you *can* use `implode` to construct an `UPDATE` query with multiple values:

```
<?php

  /* Sample data: */

  $_POST['id_table'] = array ('1746', '1834', '1944');
  $_POST['full_name'] = array ('lumbar', 'bezoar', 'sniggle');

  /* Code */

  foreach($_POST['id_table'] as $row=>$id_table)
  {
    /* Don't forget to escape data to avoid SQL injection */

    $id_table  = mysql_real_escape_string ($id_table);
    $full_name = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST['full_name'][$row]);

    $query_row[] = "'$id_table' THEN '$full_name'";
  }

  $query = "UPDATE tb_client_table_rows\n"
         . "   SET full_name = CASE id_table\n"
         . "                     WHEN "

         . implode ("\n                     WHEN ", $query_row) 

         . "\n                     ELSE full_name\n"
         . "                   END";

  echo "$query\n";
```

Output:

```sql
UPDATE tb_client_table_rows
   SET full_name = CASE id_table
                     WHEN '1746' THEN 'lumbar'
                     WHEN '1834' THEN 'bezoar'
                     WHEN '1944' THEN 'sniggle'
                     ELSE full_name
                   END
```

Note that the MySQL extension has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. You should be using [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) these days.

Comment: This would perform poorly, as you would end up updating every single row in the table.  You could easily marry this with a WHERE clause like `WHERE id_table IN (?, ?, ?, ...)` to only perform update on target rows. You could drop your ELSE condition in this case.

Comment: @MikeBrant: Nice. I should have added that I don't know how it will perform. I thought it was an interesting string building exercise. Do you think it is worth adding the `WHERE` clause or is the answer pointless rubbish either way?

Comment: @MikeBrant: Do you know for a fact that the query will hit every row, or can the `ELSE` branch be optimised away?

Comment: Without a WHERE clause, that UPDATE will update every row on the table. That is the way UPDATEs work. In fact, the note on the ELSE clause should be a dead giveaway of this (i.e. you need the ELSE to prevent blowing away data in unintended records).  You can optimize the ELSE out by doing what I mentioned and limiting the records being touched using a WHERE clause.

Comment: To your earlier question about whether it is worth it using the WHERE clause, I would say with this approach, it would be silly not to have it, since you are dynamically building the query anyway, and without the WHERE you potentially unnecessarily touch every row in the table.  Now whether this approach is better than looped single updates (ideally with prepared statement), updating across a join, etc. is really going to depends on a number of factors such as the table schema, size of table, typical/max number of rows to be updated, need for atomicity, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use implode...just do

```
$sql="UPDATE tb_client_table_rows SET full_name=$full_name WHERE id_table=$id_table";
```